# How do I create roles that grant access to a database for a new user in mariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What is the proper way to create roles, then assign new users to the roles to grant access to the desired database?

It's not working for me the way I expected.

If I try to make a read/write role and a read only role, then grant the permissions to the roles, and then create a user with a default role, I get a database access denied error for the user:

```
CREATE DATABASE testDb;

CREATE ROLE readOnly;
CREATE ROLE readWrite;

GRANT SELECT ON testDB . * TO readOnly;
GRANT ALL ON testDB . * TO readWrite;

CREATE USER 'testUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testPass';

GRANT readOnly TO testUser;
GRANT readWrite TO testUser;

SET DEFAULT ROLE readOnly FOR testUser;
\q
```

Then, when I try to connect to the database as testUser:

```
/mysql -u testUser -p -D testDb
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'testUser'@'%' to database 'testDb'
```

On the other hand, if I don't use roles and grant the permissions directly to the user, user with no roles, I don't get the database access denied error:

```
DROP USER testUser;
DROP ROLE readWrite;
DROP ROLE readOnly;

GRANT ALL ON testDb . * TO testUser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testPass';
\q
```

Now, connecting as testUser works:

```
mysql -u testUser -p -D testDb
Enter password:
MariaDB [testDb]>
```

Comment: mySQL has role support: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB, but think this question will apply to both.

Comment: Your roles statements works on `10.2.9-MariaDB`  `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;`  displays `GRANT readOnly TO 'testUser'@'%'` `GRANT readWrite TO 'testUser'@'%'` `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'testUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*88EEBA7D913688E7278E2AD071FDB5E76D76D34B'`.. i'am connecting with SQLyog to my local MariaDB server

Comment: Hrm. i'm using 10.3.2-MariaDB, and see the same results from `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;`, but still get the Access denied error when I attempt a mysql session with -D testDb. Perhaps I have a different problem than I thought?

Comment: When I log in as testUser, `show databases` does not return the testDb.

Comment: The only database listed (when in either role) is information_schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem (be careful using uppercase and lowercase in the name of the database objects):

```sql
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION();
+----------------+
| VERSION()      |
+----------------+
| 10.3.2-MariaDB |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE `testDb`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE ROLE `readOnly`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE ROLE `readWrite`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT SELECT ON `testDb`.* TO `readOnly`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL ON `testDb`.* TO `readWrite`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'testUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '*********';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT `readOnly` TO `testUser`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT `readWrite` TO `testUser`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET DEFAULT ROLE `readOnly` FOR `testUser`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> \q
Bye

$ mysql -u testUser -p
Enter password:

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| testUser@%     |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| testDb             |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CURRENT_ROLE;
+--------------+
| CURRENT_ROLE |
+--------------+
| readOnly     |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: Arg! embarrassing typo!

GRANT SELECT ON testDB

instead of 

GRANT SELECT ON testDb

Thank you very much!